# Magento not loading theme form.mini file

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have a strange issue, I am building a custom magento theme, and all of a sudden, my custom page/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml file isnt loading and its now loading the base/default one instead?

All my other theme files are loading correctly, and I have emptied the cache multiple times. I have tried altering my version of the file, but that doesnt make a difference either.

Can anyone think of anything to try? It's like something is telling it to override any other version and only use the original base version.

Running 1.9.2.4

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot - my FTP app wasnt showing the current live verison... I logged back in and noticed my template had vanished. Re-added, altered and voila!